# Cant connect to remote mysql database by php

Tags: php, mysql

Ok this seems stupid and i feel stupid to ask, but I've been goggling for a while and i have no idea what the answers are talking about;

I'm trying to connect to my remote live mysql database through php here's my code

```
<?php
// Connecting to the db
$con = mysqli_connect("166.**.*.**","username","password","MyDb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

echo "Con successful";

// Reach the table "demo"
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['Title']." ".$row['Description']." ".$row['Link'];
}

// Close connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And here's the result:

> Con successful Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't
>   connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) in
>   /home/content/83/11483383/html/Perceptive mind
>   new/php/page-builder/portfolio.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server
>   could not be established in /home/content/83/11483383/html/Perceptive
>   mind new/php/page-builder/portfolio.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource,
>   boolean given in /home/content/83/11483383/html/Perceptive mind
>   new/php/page-builder/portfolio.php on line 15

Comment: **Ahem**, you're mixing MySQL APIs, they do **not** mix. Rum & coke do, but not this.

Comment: You mixed up `mysql_*` which you shouldn't use anymore because it's deprecated and the still maintained `mysqli`. Convert everything to `mysqli`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start out by opening a connection to your remote database with the `mysqli_` library.

You then try to query it using the deprecated `mysql_` library.

The documentation for that function says:

> If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated.

The two libraries are not compatible. Since you haven't opened a connection using `mysql_`, it tries to open one (defaulting to using localhost via a socket) and fails.

Be consistent about the library you are using. Stick to `mysqli_` throughout.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a connection with `mysqli` you have to use it and not the old `mysql` functions. That not working.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: old = mysql -> new = mysql(i)